# Microsoft SQL server 2008 and UTF-8

Tags: sql-server, utf-8

A colleague tells me that there is no way to bulk insert UTF-8 encoded data into a Microsoft SQL server 2008.

Can this be true? Is there any stuff you would recommend him to read or look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true.  The [documentation for BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28SQL.105%29.aspx) says 'SQL Server [2008] does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding)'.

There was once a Microsoft Connect Page about this issue, but Connect is now gone.

Comment: Very interesting link (connect page). And also a bit scary to read the microsoft response.

Comment: I am accepting this as an answer, since it has been open for such a long time.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 isn't a part of SQL Server's Unicode strategy (unfortunately). However, UTF-8 is well supported in .NET. If you are willing to write .NET code, you could use the `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy` class in conjunction with a `System.IO.StreamReader` and/or `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8'.

Another option is Integration Services. For file connections, you can choose code page `65001 (UTF-8)`.

Comment: Actually, there is no .NET used here. It's a windows development enviroment running Cold Fusion on the server with a MS SQL server 2008 backend. 

All tools have to understand the encoding chosen. Right now, the chosen encoding is ISO-8859-1 (latin 1).

Comment: <Actually, there is no .NET used here> See the part about using Integration Services. Alternatively, if you are into Powershell, you could call all the needed .NET things from there.